# every set intersection for every set in a family with another family of sets

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, sets

I want to find for each list within a list of lists what intersections occur when taking set intersection for each list in another list of lists.

Hopefully that makes sense.

I have tried

```
Outer[Intersection[#1, #2] &, p1, p2]
MapThread[Intersection, {p1, p2}] (* This works but only when p1 and p2 are same length *)
```

where `p1 = {{1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}}` and `p2= {{3, 5, 6}}`
But no such luck.
The output should show that `6` is the only number in common between the list in p2 and each list in p1. If p2 contains another list, then the comparision function should perform the same check as with the 1st list in p2 but only care about the intersections that happen between this 2nd list and all the lists in p1.

I also should mention that when no intersections occur between list i in p1 with list j in p2 then something need to denote this (like `{}`)

Ideally I want and output like
result = `{{{6},{6},{6}},{*results for 2nd element in p2*}}` etc.

Comment: Why is the third element of the desired result not `{3,5,6}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mobile, so not tested

```
Intersection@@#& /@ Tuples[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Update. Another solution, which preserves the inner/outer structure:

```
Table[Intersection[l1, l2], {l1, p1}, {l2, p2}]
```

Comment: Nice. yes this returns same as mine. But I'm realizing that I need to organize the intersections into subcollections when comparing against a fixed list within the list of lists. (think each set of intersections corresponds to the index of the outside loop).

Comment: `Table[Intersection[l1,l2], {l1, p1}, {l2, p2}]`

Comment: Table is a poor man’s map ;)

Comment: perfect. I updated mine as well (the old fashioned way). Do you know how I can print this into a table to see the results a bit easier? (giving you the answer either way).

Comment: Look at `Grid`, which should work with the Table output

Comment: I just added `// TableForm[#, 
   TableHeadings -> {{"p1(1)", "p1(2)"}, {"p2(1)", "p2(2)"}}] &` which is a bit rough but works

Comment: You should be able to just write `Intersection@@@Tuples[{p1, p2}]` for the first example

Answer (score 4):

```
Outer[Intersection, p1, p2, 1]
```

> {{{6}}, {{6}}, {{3, 5, 6}}}

Comment: can't believe I only needed to add `,1]` Welp won't be getting back those hours.

Comment: Don't fret too much about that. Consider it a rite of passage. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the naive way (hoping for a more idiomatic, functional soln from someone).

````
p1 = {{1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}};
p2 = {{3, 5, 6}};
list = {}
Do[
 AppendTo[list, {}]
  Do[

   If[IntersectingQ[p1[[x]], p2[[y]]], 
    Intersection[p1[[x]], p2[[y]]] // AppendTo[list[[y]], #] &, 
    Nothing]

   , {x, 1, Length[p1]}]
 , {y, 1, Length[p2]}]
list
```
````